# What is the difference between an am ha'aretz vs an apikores?

Tags: rabbis

In Rabbinic philosophy what was the difference between somebody that was an am ha’aretz vs an apikores?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a kofer and apicorsis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36706/what-is-the-difference-between-a-kofer-and-apicorsis), which asks about these terms in addition to others.